# WPF/C#: Images rotating from a listview?

Tags: wpf, database, listview, image

I just want ask for your comments/suggestions on how to create a customized listview (if that's a good implementation) in WPF that displays images coming from a table from a database (more like a playlist) that rotates similar to a film (moving horizontally - on loop)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list of Images, you can create an Image control for each one, put each Image control in a horizontal StackPanel, put the StackPanel inside a Canvas (of whatever size of the "film"), and animate the Left property of the Canvas to have the images roll.

Of course, if you need that the images wrap (the first one after the last one), you could forget about the StackPanel and move each Image separately.

Comment: Not the exact I'm looking for but I made a good implementation almost similar to your answer. I've created two StackPanel, 'wrapped' them and made an animation/storyboard that would like a film effect - on loop..