# How to rotate the images wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, image, animation

I want to create a smooth moving of images. i have gone the following link but i dont know how to implement.  [WPF/C#: Images rotating from a listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772520/wpf-c-images-rotating-from-a-listview)

Geetha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at [RotateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.aspx) in combination with animations.

Here is a nice article how to implement it ;)

http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2006102701.aspx